# What is the earliest Hook a Script can use?

Tags: functions, jquery, hooks, actions

At present, I am disabling Right Click through the use of the following code:

```
<?php
// Disable Right Click
function disable_right_click() {
?>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'disable_right_click');
add_action('admin_head', 'disable_right_click');
?>
```

The only problem is, the right click feature works for a second or 2 as the page is loading.  I assume this is because the script loads quite late.

Is there any way to get the above code loaded instantly?  Possible being the first script to load?

The code does not seem to work with earlier Hooks, such as `init`, `pre_get_posts` and `get_header`.  Nor does the use of an integer work.  For example:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'disable_right_click', 1);
```

Any ideas on how I can get the above script to be the first script loaded?

Comment: You've wrapped your script in `jQuery(document).ready(...)`, which means 'run this when the page has finished loading'. So it's not going to matter where you put this on the page. wp_head is probably the right place to put this though if you're going to write it straight into the page, or wp_enqueue_scripts if you're going to emit it with wp_enqueue_script instead.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see.  Ideally, I wanted to insert `oncontextmenu="return false;"` into the `<body>` tags.  I have achieved this for the thematic file but cannot seem to figure out how to insert such code into the `<body>` tags for the WP Dashboard and Login pages.  Any suggestions on that front?